# how to get nested json using retrofit in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

My nested json is {"name":{"first_name":"rohit","last_name":"sharma"}}

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the error that you're getting?
The POJO here looks ok to me.
Also the image you linked seems to be no longer accessible

Answer (score 0):

From your example.

The:

```
private name first_name;
```

Should be:

```
private String first_name:
```

The same goes for last_name:

```
private String last_name;
```

And getFirst_name() and getLast_name() should also retturn String.

And you should start class names with uppercase. It's a [java naming convention](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-naming-conventions).